# Argument of a complex number and negative

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How do you prove that if $x>0$ then $arg(-x)=\pi -arctan(x)$. Geometrically this is clear. How would you prove it formally?

Comment: $$ arg(-x) = arg(-1) + arg(x) = \pi + arg(x)$$? by arg you mean the argument of a complex number? Where did that arctangent came from?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation

Comment: @Mefitico values of the angle are in range $[0,2\pi]$. If $x>0$ then $-x$ lies in the negative real axis.Thus its angle is given by  $\pi$ $-$ $arctan(x)$. No?

Comment: You could do arctan(b/a) to get the angle equivalent to arg(x) but finding arctan(x) in this case makes no sense. While arctan is defined for complex numbers, it returns a complex number unlike arg(x)

Comment: @Gabe I meant to write $arctan(0)$, instead of $x$.

Comment: check the formula for the argument at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number)